# A follow-up to "Extracting data from an API using R"

Tags: r, json, list, dataframe, extract

The code I have (which comes from here [A continuation of... Extracting data from an API using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575231/a-continuation-of-extracting-data-from-an-api-using-r)) gives a very complicated output. I can extract almost all I need except for a data.frame that's nested within the list.

Without doing anything, it gives me this error:

Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’, ‘10’, ‘11’, ‘12’, ‘13’, ‘14’, ‘15’, ‘16’, ‘17’, ‘18’, ‘19’, ‘2’, ‘20’, ‘3’, ‘4’, ‘5’, ‘6’, ‘7’, ‘8’, ‘9’

If I try to flatten or unlist, it comes up NULL.

In the example code, I've added some variables that are easy to get and number 42 is "dokintressent", from which I need "intressent", a list of names for each case. I have to run APIs from the Swedish legislative a half a dozen times, but this is the trickier one.

When I remove 42, it makes the data.frame perfectly.

```
my_dfs1 <- lapply(1:207, function(i){
  my_url <- paste0("http://data.riksdagen.se/dokumentlista/?sok=&doktyp=mot&rm=&from=2017-01-01&tom=2017-12-31&ts=&bet=&tempbet=&nr=&org=&iid=&webbtv=&talare=&exakt=&planering=&sort=rel&sortorder=desc&rapport=&utformat=json&a=s&p=", i)
  r1 <- GET(my_url)
  r2 <- rawToChar(r1$content)
  r3 <- fromJSON(r2)
  r4 <- r3$dokumentlista$dokument
  return(r4)
})

df <- my_dfs1 %>% lapply(function(df_0){
  df_0[c(12:14, 18, 42)]
}) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
```

EDIT: I've noticed that the data I want is actually several data.frames per case. From "intressent", I need "namn". Basically, I need the final database to look like this:

```
                     V12     V13    V14    V18    Namn
    Motion 1                                     c(name1, name2)
```

Comment: The thing is only you can decide how the data should be represented, or rather how you wanted to be. `intressent` has a data frame per row, how does this data frame fit  the original data frame (a.k.a `df_0` in you the code above)? how do you imagine the end result you want to get?
Do you want, for example, to repeat each row from `df_0[c(12:14, 18])` for the rows in `intressent`?

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question, since I've realized the data.frame per row issue as well. What I **really** need is "namn", which would be great if it could come as a column with each cell reflecting a list of names. 
I need all of it to be one single database that I can work with later. Thank you so much for doing this. I definitely bit off a bit more than I can chew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to work on `intressent` on its own and extract from it what you need and then assign it to a new column, just make sure you get a simple data structure per row.

You can also, if it works better for you, paste the names together, separated by '-', for example, and then `intressent` will be a simple character vector.

```
df <- my_dfs1 %>% lapply(function(df_0){
  #choose the columns you want
  return_df <- df_0[c(12:14, 18)]
  # work on intressent
  return_df$namn <- df_0$dokintressent$intressent %>% 
    lapply(function(x)list(x$namn)) %>% 
    do.call(rbind, .)                    # careful here a simple unlist won't work
  return(return_df) }) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)
```

Comment: I thought about that - that it should be worked on its own - but I didn't know where to begin. Sorry to ask as I'm sure you've considered this, but in the end they'll be assigned back to the correct cases? Who works with whom is one of my main hypothesis.

Comment: I ran it a couple of times and it comes back as a list, using all the would-be columns - maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, for example what do you get if you run `df$namn[1] %>% str()`?

Comment: I don't know what I didn't wrong before, but it's working now. It wasn't coming back as a data.frame but a large matrix. I'm so sorry have kept bothering you and I would love to give you proper credit if you'll let me (beyond thanking you by using your handle in my acknowledgments).

Comment: That' perfectly fine! And it wasn't a bother at all, I'm glad to help

Comment: and before I forget, please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, of course! Done and done. If you wanna send me your name in private, please do.

Comment: If you're still up for it, @DS_UNI... One last question (I promise!): for this API (data.riksdagen.se/dokumentlista/…), I haven't been able to do the same and get "talare" in the place of "intressent", although the format seems to be same. The error message is this: Error in df_0$debatt$anforande : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors Called from: eval(lhs, parent, parent). Again, thank you!

Comment: not sure where is this `talare` is, but the error message states that you're trying to get `df_0$debatt$anforande` , however `df_0$debatt` is a vector which means you can  not use `$ ` with it

Comment: This particular variable for this API comes after `dokintressent` does (since in this case the latter is null). So, it would be dokumentlista>dokument>debatt>anforande>talare. `talare` is a variable within a data.frame; anforade is a data.frame list. That's why it struck me as odd that it didn't work as it did before. In fact, it's also a list of names, it just means "speaker". Thanks for coming back!

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't find `dokumentlista` at all, try to make the problem more specific. As a way to understand better what is happening, choose one page and work with it and take it one step at a time, for example take a look at the column you want to work with from one element of `my_dfs1`, if it's a list take a look at the first element from this list and so on, and of-course it's much easier to help you if I can see what you tried.

Comment: Right, sorry. `dokumentlista` is flattened in the first piece of code.

  my_dfs3 <- lapply(1:302, function(i){
  my_url <- paste0("http://data.riksdagen.se/dokumentlista/?sok=&doktyp=bet&rm=&from=2000-01-01&tom=2017-12-31&ts=&bet=&tempbet=&nr=&org=&iid=&webbtv=&talare=&exakt=&planering=&sort=rel&sortorder=desc&rapport=&utformat=json&a=s&p=", i)
  r1 <- GET(my_url)
  r2 <- rawToChar(r1$content)
  r3 <- fromJSON(r2)
  r4 <- r3$dokumentlista$dokument
  return(r4)
})

Afte that, I added the 2nd code  (TBC)

Comment: I simply changed what I was looking for, since `debatt` here seems to be in the same format as `dokintressent`

    df <- my_dfs3 %>% lapply(function(df_0){
      return_df <- df_0[c(12:14, 18)]
      return_df$talare <- df_0$debatt$anforande %>% 
        lapply(function(x)list(x$talare)) %>% 
        do.call(rbind, .)                    
  return(return_df) }) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
  
It then gave the atomic vector error. I tried a bunch of things, but I'm still too new at this. I managed to clunkinly get the names for 2017, but that was it.

Comment: but it's not the same format, at least not when I'm getting the data, have you looked at `my_dfs1[[1]]$debatt`?

Comment: Just did it. It prints out 20 data chunks, but I know that there are more.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I decided to retry the second piece of code (search for `talare`) and it worked this time! Is R alive? I'm so so sorry to have bothered you so much and for something that I can't even explain. I don't even know how to thank you.